# Why is there only one independent variable for a line integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves, line-integrals

I read from a textbook that

> The essential point to understand about a line integral is that there is *one* independent variable, because we are required to remain on a *curve*.

How does remaining on a *curve* result in only *one* independent variable for the line integral, for both 2D and 3D cases?

Comment: Curves require one parameter to generate. Compare to a surface (and so a surface integral) which needs two parameters.

Comment: Think about a parametric equation for a straight line. How many independent variables does that have? Does this number change if the dimension of the enclosing space changes?

Comment: The nature of a *curve* is that it is inherently a one-dimensional object. If you're an ant crawling along the curve, you have only one degree of freedom — and you can go forwards or backwards. The curve can live in 179 dimensions (or, in fact, in infinitely many). Still, the parametrization of that curve will involve only *one* *independent variable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any curve can be parametrized by a function $f(t)$, where $t \in [0,1]$ typically.

$f(0)$ represents the beginning, or start of your curve, and $f(1)$ the end. If your curve is in multiple dimensions, you can parametrize it such that each of the functions depends on only the variable $t$:

$$x(t) = \quad ...$$
$$y(t) = \quad ...$$
$$z(t) = \quad ...$$

You can thus project your curve in $n$-dimensional space onto each dimension, $x, y, z$, etc... and then define a function that will parameterize that dimension. This system of equations only depends on a single parameter, $t$, which dictates which $x, y,$ and $z$ coordinates must be taken in order to "stay on the curve".